# How to remove recessed cupboard lip and drywall over the cupboard?

Tags: drywall

Our dining room has a gas fireplace under a large window. The fireplace is off center and there is a large recessed cupboard to the left of the fireplace that is also off center. It looks ridiculous and is driving me nuts. Is it possible to remove the cupboard (or just pull the lip off) and drywall over it? I’m wanting do drywall over it and brick the whole thing to look better. I included a picture for reference. I’m also not sure if it’s something my husband and I can tackle or if we need a professional. Any suggestions are welcome.[image]

Comment: That would drive me crazy too!

Comment: Interior Design by Pablo Picasso™

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is not that big of a job,
You will need to add a support in the center and possibly around the premier.
After a simple framework is there to allow you to screw or nail the dry wall to (every one uses screws now) the new cut to size peace can be added.

Now comes the more difficult part but still a DIY “tape and texture. The seam will need a thin layer of mud then a strip of special paper or mesh called tape is pressed into the mud and allowed to dry, then sanded and another coat is usually needed (some times 3 or 4 for a new to DIY when the surface looks good time to match the texture there are spray cans if it’s an orange peal if another type it may take some more questions and watching utube videos but with Somme patience you can eliminate the cabinet and turn it into a wall space.

Answer (score 1):

**Removing the cupboard:** If it were not for the textured wall I would say this is a perfect learning project.  You can take your time, make mistakes and correct them at a fairly low cost.  Worst case you waste a small piece of drywall.  You only need basic tools. However if you are unable to match the texture, IMO it will look worse than it does now and you'll have to call in a professional to finish the job or resurface the entire wall.  If I bit this off at all, I'd buy some drywall to practice the finish before beginning demolition.

**Bricking it over:**. Not sure what you mean by this, but building an actual brick wall inside a house is not a beginner's DIY project for many reasons.  If you mean you want to use light weight glue-on brick tiles to resurface the entire wall .... that too is a good learning project and eliminates the texture problem.  You need to make sure the wall surface is ready, ie, no peeling paint or other issues that would make it fail.